# How to set progress bar value using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a servlet to download files online. For this, I have made a progress bar element in jsp.

```
<progress id="p1" max="100" value="0"><span>0</span>%</progress>
```

and the java script code to update the progress value:

```
function setProgress(value)
{
var progressBar = document.getElementById("p1");
progressBar.value = value;
progressBar.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent = value;
}
```

Now, In the servlet code to change the progress:

```
InputStream is = ..........;
byte[] bytes = new byte[size*1024];
int read = in.read();
for(int j=0;read!=-1;j++)
{
   bytes[j] = (byte)read;
   setProgress((int)getProgressDownload(bytes.length));
   read = in.read();
}

public float getProgressDownload(int dsize)
{
    return ((float)dsize/tsize)*100;//tsize is total file's size;
}
public void setProgress(int value)
{
    try
    {
       response.getWriter().write("<script>");
       response.getWriter().write("setProgress(\"p1\","+value+");");
       response.getWriter().write("</script>");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that is makes the HTML code lengthy because for every byte it will print a script code.

**What should I do to prevent this?**

Thanks for help

Comment: Better to use AJAX based approach for this task.

Comment: How can I do this ? Can you explain me?

Comment: @ParkashKumar is right.. use a AJAX for same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi first I think you should store the process in session. And then using ajax call you can regularly update the progress bar using response received from below some servlet. Add the mapping and all I am just writing the doGet stuff..
Also I assume URL mapping as 'progressServlet' for this particular servlet..
Below is doGet method

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String downloadId = "longProcess_" + request.getParameter("downloadId");
        LongProcess longProcess = (LongProcess) request.getSession().getAttribute(downloadId);
        int progress = longProcess.getProgress();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(progress));
    }
```

And then in JS you can use setTimeout() /setInterval() to call checkProgress  method given below at certain intervals and stop calling if progress received is 100% complete.  You can use this to repeatedly fire Ajax requests to request current status of the progress.

```
var refreshprogessbar = setInterval(checkProgress, 10000);// 10 seconds
function checkProgress() {/*pass the actual id instead of 12345*/
    $.getJSON('progressServlet?downloadId=12345', function(progress) {
        if(progress == 100){clearInterval(refreshprogessbar);}
        setProgress(progress);
    });
}
```

LongProcess is basically the class you use to keep track of the on going process. Below is the example of one of such:

```
class LongProcess extends Thread {
    private int progress;
    public void run() {
        while (progress < 100) {
            try { sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            progress++;
        }
    }    
    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }
}
```

I am just incrementing the progress filed member but you can have a setProgress() method and add logic to increase the progress.

Comment: Sir, I was unable to understand about **LongProcess** class that you have mentioned. What is it? Can I connect **MyServlet**  (in which the download is being processed in a thread) to the **progressServlet** so that it can fetch the values of the progress?  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Rajnishkumar I have edited the answer.. check and let me know.. If its helpful please accept the answer..